# Show alert if clicked element is other than anchor tag

Tags: jquery, click, alert

I want an alert only if clicked element is not a link

```
$('.boxT').click(function(){
    if ($(this).prop("tagName") == "a") {return};
    alert ("323");
});
```

Deesn't work.

Comment: `"a"` should be `"A"`, not sure but should try. Also `tagName` is a standard JS property, you can just write `this.tagName` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can exclude the anchor tags while the binding time,

```
$('.boxT').not("a").click(function(){

    alert ("323");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
$('.boxT:not(a)').click(function(){
    alert ("323");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using **[.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)**:

```
$('.boxT').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is("a")) {return};
    alert("323");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use capital `A` to check with the tag name since the property tagName would return the result as capital one,

```
$('.boxT').click(function(){
    if ($(this).prop("tagName") == "A") {return};
    alert ("323");
});
```

or the better solution would be,

```
$('.boxT').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is("a") {return};
    alert ("323");
});
```